# Working on DynamoDB in your computer without AWS credentials

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am learning DynamoDB. I had installed DynamoDB local copy in my computer. Is it possible to perform operations like create-table on DynamoDB with out having aws credentials?

Comment: Can you guys please explain why you have downvoted this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using DynamoDB local you don't need any credentials, just put any string as Access Key and Secret Key.

Only thing you need to make sure is that all your code listen to the local port, by default it will listen on 8000

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html) is the link on how to set up your local environment.