# CRUD operations on DynamoDB local in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I want to do some CRUD operations in DynamoDB local in java. I don't have any aws credentials. I have done all the settings to setup the local environment and also I created the tables and can see in aws CLI also.

Already refered [Working on DynamoDB in your computer without AWS credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148490/working-on-dynamodb-in-your-computer-without-aws-credentials) question but it has no java code examples to do the operations.

I tried the code,

```
AmazonDynamoDB ddb = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient();

        try {
            ddb.deleteTable("book");
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

but this gives an error

```
"The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service"
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Does AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder configure to local dynamo endpoint?

Comment: when I run the command "aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000" in aws CLI, it shows me the tables I created @Jerry06

Comment: try this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.Java.html#CodeSamples.Java.RegionAndEndpoint

Comment: after adding 'AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
    new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "us-east-1"))
    .build(); '  , I am getting an compilation error "awsclientbuilder.endpointconfiguration cannot be resolved to a type". Is there any dependencies should I have to include to the pom file to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating the client like this then you can execute CRUD operation,

```
    AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDBClient = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
    AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvide = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
    AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder clientBuilder = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard();
    clientBuilder.setCredentials(credentialsProvide);

    EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000/", "local");
    clientBuilder.setEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration);
    dynamoDBClient = clientBuilder.build();
```